# Don't know how to format celery message from rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Using this as a guide: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html#definition
I am trying to send messages to my celery program, but I dont know how to format the messages. Whatever I try, I get cryptic errors from celery that are either `KeyError: 'chord'` or `ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)'`. Where can I find information on how to format these messages. Im just trying to accomplish this from the rabbitmq web interface.

This is what my celery app looks like:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://ycunrxpq:nU31gS9yTlbFNC0vXJFpU7P9GxmzHkk8@orangutan.rmq.cloudamqp.com/ycunrxpq')

@app.task
def random_task():
    print('this task is random')
```

What is the bare minimum I need to enter here:
[image: rabbitmq web interface]

For it to actually run the task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is could be useful for you but I remember that I had a similar problem.

Just pass 'content_type', 'content_encoding' in the properties and 'eta' and 'taskname' ( without tasks. ) in the header.

Also, I remember that kwargs and args are mandatory.

This is an example of my task

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://logstash:logstash@rabbitmq.local:5672')

app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('logstash_events', Exchange('logstash_events'), routing_key='logstash_events'),

)

app.conf.task_default_queue = 'logstash_events'
app.conf.task_default_exchange_type = 'direct'
app.conf.task_default_routing_key = 'logstash_events'

@app.task(serializer='json', name='process_next_task', bind=True)
def process_next_task(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.message = kwargs.get('message',"null")
    self.geodata = kwargs.get('geodata',"null")
    print(self.message)
    print(self.geodata)
```

These are the params (Ruby in Logstash) that I'm passing from Logstash but I think is the same.

```
event.set('task', 'process_next_task')
event.set('lang', 'py')
event.set('origin', '@logstash')
event.set('id', event.get('fingerprint'))
event.set('args', {:empty => 'null'})
event.set('kwargs', {
  :message    => {
    :data => event.get('data'),
    :event_type => event.get('event_type'),
  },
  :geodata    => event.get('geoip')
})
```

Comment: I assume this is rails?
I'm still not able to get around the chord error
Just to clarify, you dont specify chord anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, it's really a bad help, I know  :)
Yes,  the 2nd snippet is Ruby ( inside Logstash ). 
I've posted it just for show you the parameters.

Inside Celery, I've changed the default task queue (I've updated my snippet ).

Honestly, I've never tried to trigger a task through the RabbitMQ interface.

I have a couple of scripts in PHP and JS (node) and a Logstash instance that triggers task without any problems with this configuration

Keep in mind that I'm not expert of RabbitMQ.